# How do you sum multiple values gotten from inputs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is part of a series of exercises I have been doing and it's the only one I haven't been able to complete (I'm a Javascript beginner). The exercise says to "Create an input, and a button, so that everytime a value is entered the total value is stored in a variable. Create another button, that when pressed shows the accumulated total."

I have tried this:

JavaScript:

```
function ex15Save(ex15Num){
    let num1 = document.getElementById("ex15Num");
    var ex15Num = num1;
    let ex15Storage;
    ex15Storage += ex15Num;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label>Number to store 
<input id="ex15Num" type="number"> </label>
<button onclick="ex15Save()">Save Total</button>
<button onclick="ex15Show()">Show total</button>
<p id="ex15Total"></p>
```

I know the code is not even close to being finished but it has gotten to a point where my brain can't comprehend how to store the sum of the values without overwriting the value of a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get total sum from input box values using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript)

Comment: 1) You need `num1.value` and not just `num1`, 2) If you put your variable declaration outside of the function, it will keep its value across invocations.

Comment: also: [How to get sum of input values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745185/how-to-get-sum-of-input-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Declare ex15Storage outside the function otherwise it will reset everytime the function is called */
let ex15Storage = 0;

function ex15Save(){
    let num1 = document.getElementById("ex15Num");
      /* the num1 is an object so you want the value from it..  also format the value to number
      Otherwise 0 + "123" = 0123 // num + string is numstring value 
      */ 
    let ex15Num = Number(num1.value);
    ex15Storage += ex15Num;
    console.log(ex15Storage)
}
function ex15Show(){
  document.getElementById("ex15Total").innerHTML = ex15Storage;
}
```

```html
<label>Number to store 
<input id="ex15Num" type="number"> </label>
<button onclick="ex15Save()">Save Total</button>
<button onclick="ex15Show()">Show total</button>
  
  
<p id="ex15Total"></p>
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't even have to wait, this answer is correct, it worked wonderfully, it's very compact and I understood instantly what the error was when comparing with my code, thank you very much.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do here, but the basic logic is thus:

Create a new variable (`total`), and add the value of the input to it every time the button is clicked. You'll notice the use of `parseFloat()` to ensure that the value can be added.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('ex15Num');
const output = document.getElementById('ex15Total');
const saveButton = document.getElementById('ex15SaveButton');
const showButton = document.getElementById('ex15ShowButton');
let total = 0;

saveButton.addEventListener('click',  (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const toAdd = parseFloat(input.value);
  
  if (!isNaN(toAdd)) {
    total+= toAdd;
    input.value = '';
  }
});

showButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  output.innerText = total;
});
```

```html
<label for="ex15Num">Number to store</label>
<input id="ex15Num" type="number">
<button id="ex15SaveButton">Save Total</button>
<button id="ex15ShowButton">Show total</button>

<p id="ex15Total"></p>
```

Also, avoid using intrusive event handlers, and instead bind your events with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer my question, even though this response falls out of my scope I have been able to acquire a bit more knowledge and I'm sure it'll help on the next exercises. I will talk to my teacher when he has some free time and I'll try to update this question with however I solve this. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified function

```js
let inputEl = document.getElementById("number1");
let totalEl = document.getElementById("total");
let total = 0;

let sumx = function(...nums){
  return nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

let addition = () => {
  total = sumx(total,parseInt(inputEl.value));
  totalEl.innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input value="0" type="text" id="number1">
<button onclick="addition()">ADD</button>
<h1 id="total">00</h1>
```